# GAEにおけるObjectifyを使用したクエリについて

Tags: java, google-app-engine

お世話になっております。

環境
GAE 1.9.25
objectify: 5.1.9

現在GAEを利用しWebアプリケーションを作成しているのですが、以下の状態の場合にCursorが取得できず、nullになってしまいます。
keywords内にtagListの要素が1つでも入っていれば取得したいと考えています。

```
Query<Hoge> query = ofy().load().type(Hoge.class).limit(limit);
query = query.filter("tagList in", keywords);
QueryResultIterator<Hoge> iterator = query.iterator();
List<Hoge> result = new ArrayList<Hoge>(query.count());
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Hoge hoge = iterator.next();
        result.add(hoge);
}
log.info("cursor = " + iterator.getCursor());
```

以上のコードを実行するとgetCursorでCursorがnullになってしまいます。
keywords.length == 1の場合は正常に稼働するのですが、1つ以上の要素になるとこのような挙動になってしまいます。

なぜCursorがnullになる現象になるのでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 単純に全件取得済になってるとか？

Comment: 早速のコメントありがとうございます。
全件取得済みでもCursorはnullにはならないようです。

Comment: ちょっと、最近あんまりJava書いてないので、今週末にでもコード書いてみます

Comment: わざわざ申し訳ありません。お時間があれば宜しくお願い致します。私も進捗があればここに記します。

Answer (score 4):

だいぶ前の質問なので解決済かもしれませんが・・

`hoge IN (a, b, c)` みたいな条件は基本的にDatastoreのインデックスの仕組み上検索することができません。

GAE/JavaはIN filterをサポートしていますが、これは`hoge = a` , `hoge = b`, `hoge = c` の3つのクエリを実行してSDKライブラリ内部で結果をマージしているものと思われます。

ですので、INを使用した場合はカーソルが返せないのだと思います。
INの条件が1つの場合は実質 `hoge = a` の1クエリになるのでカーソルが返ってくるのでしょう。

参考:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/query-cursors

> Because the NOT_EQUAL and IN operators are implemented with multiple queries, queries that use them do not support cursors, nor do composite queries constructed with the CompositeFilterOperator.or method.